# MySQL, count distict elements across months

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have SELECT to count distict elements across months. But if few elements have the same name and are in different months then DISTINCT works in each month separetely

```
SELECT 
    YEAR( `date` ) AS "year",
    MONTH( `date` ) AS "month", 
    count( DISTINCT name ) AS "howmany" 
FROM 
    `XYZ` 
GROUP BY
    name,
    year,
    month
ORDER BY 
    `date` DESC
```

Data:

```
_________________________
|01-01-2018  |  name1    |
|01-02-2018  |  name1    |
```

Returns:

```
2018  |  01  |   1
2018  |  02  |   1
```

and I want:

```
2018  |  02  |   2
```

Is it possible? How to fix query?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Oracle here, don't have a MySQL handy, so you'll have to adapt the query, but I hope you get the idea:

```
select XYZ.d, XYZ.name, a.howmany
from XYZ
join (select name, count(name) as howmany from XYZ group by name ) a
on XYZ.name = a.name
```